# DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3 causing database to not be created in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, indexeddb

I'm building a phonegap android application using angularjs. The following code works perfectly fine in browsers, but on a real android mobile device (android version 4.1.2) the window.indexeddb is firing the alert that window.indexeddb is true, but when I go to call the checkForDuplicate method, I get the following error:

NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3

```
stocks.factory('database', ['$resource', '$http', '$q', function($resource, $http, $q) {
var dataMethods = {
    addStock: function(stock, nameofcompany) {
        var _this = this;
        alert("About to add stock");
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //Get a transaction
        //default for OS list is all, default for type is read
        var transaction = this.db.transaction(["portfolio"], "readwrite");
        //Ask for the objectStore
        var store = transaction.objectStore("portfolio");
        //Define a person
        var stockTemplate = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
            company_name: nameofcompany,
            name: stock,
            created: new Date()
        }
        //Perform the add
        var request = store.add(stockTemplate);
        request.onerror = function(e) {
            alert("failed to add stock to portflio", e.target.error.name);
            deferred.reject(e);
        }
        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
            alert("successfully added stock to portfolio");
            deferred.resolve(e);
            //alert(store);
            //_this.readOnlyStock();
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    readOnlyStock: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var transaction = this.db.transaction(["portfolio"], "readonly");
        var store = transaction.objectStore("portfolio");
        // var cursorRequest = store.openCursor();
        var arrayOfStocks = [];
        var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0);
        var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(keyRange);
        cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            var cursor = e.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                arrayOfStocks.push(cursor.value);
                //deferred.resolve(arrayOfStocks);
                //return deferred.promise;
                cursor.
                continue ();
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(arrayOfStocks);
            }
        }
        cursorRequest.onerror = function() {
            alert('could not fetch data');
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    deleteStock: function(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        alert('starting delete');
        var transaction = this.db.transaction(["portfolio"], "readwrite");
        var store = transaction.objectStore("portfolio");
        var request = store.delete(id);
        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
            alert('deleted item');
            deferred.resolve();
        };
        request.onerror = function(e) {
            alert(e);
        };
        alert('done deleting');
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    checkForDuplicate: function(stockRequestedToAdd) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        alert('starting search');
        var transaction = this.db.transaction(["portfolio"]);
        var store = transaction.objectStore("portfolio");
        var index = store.index("name");
        var request = index.get(stockRequestedToAdd);
        alert('got here');
        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
            deferred.resolve(e);
        };
        request.onerror = function(e) {
            alert('could not do search');
        };
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
//return dataMethods;
if (window.indexedDB) {
    alert('indexeddb supported!');
//if (navigator.indexedDB || navigator.mozIndexedDB) {
    //window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase('users_stocks');
    alert('indexeddb is supported');
    var openRequest = indexedDB.open("users_stocks", 7);
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        alert("upgrade needed");
        var thisDB = e.target.result;
        //if (!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("portfolio")) {
        alert('created object store');
        var createStore = thisDB.createObjectStore("portfolio", {
            autoIncrement: true,
            keyPath: "id"
        });
        createStore.createIndex("name", "name", {
            unique: true
        });
        //}
    }
    openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        alert('connection opened');
        alert(e.target.result.version);
        dataMethods.db = e.target.result;
    }
    openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
        alert('could not open connection');
    }
    return dataMethods;
} else {
    alert('indexedDB not supported');
} }]);
```

I'm thinking the openRequest.onupgradeneeded has not fired resulting in the object store not getting created. Also the alert(e.target.result.version) is not providing any value.

thanks!

Comment: seems like this issue starts in checkforduplicates at the line where it is - var transaction = this.db.transaction(["portfolio"]);

Comment: the complete error i'm getting is this: {message: "NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3", code: 3, name: "NOT_FOUND_ERR", reThrown: true, NO_ERR: 0, UNKNOWN_ERR: 1, NON_TRANSIENT_ERR: 2, NOT_FOUND_ERR: 3, CONSTRAINT_ERR: 4, DATA_ERR: 5, NOT_ALLOWED_ERR: 6, SERIAL_ERR: 7, RECOVERABLE_ERR: 8, TRANSIENT_ERR: 9, TIMEOUT_ERR: 10, DEADLOCK_ERR: 11, READ_ONLY_ERR: 12, ABORT_ERR: 13}

Comment: try to open the db with a higher version this way you are sure the onupgradeneeded event will be triggerd and you can create the objectstore